# Ajuda em passar um código do jsFiddle para um arquivo HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, revisão-de-código

Eu tenho um código nesse [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/098LvLat/2/) que eu alterei, porém agora estou a ter dificuldades em passá-lo para um arquivo HTML.

Meu código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    th, td {
        padding: 5px;
        border:1px solid black;
    }
    .esconder {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var executa = function() {

    var json = `'[{"trechoorigem":"CGH","trechodestino":"CWB","dataprocessamento":null,"sobrenomepassageiro":"TESTE","statusintegracao":"PENDENTE","tipoproduto":"AEREO","datasaida":1440069600000,"dataconclusaovenda":1438345534000,"idpostoatendimento":null,"tipointegracao":"CONCLUSAO","confirmacao":null,"idintegracao":1113,"dataemissaovenda":1438354800000,"fornecedor":"JJ","idproduto":22078,"nomepassageiro":"PASSAGEIRO","idsolicitacao":21192,"datacriacaovenda":1438345245000,"localizador":"5RAHNZ","datachegada":1440073380000,"localizadorgds":"false","postoatendimento":"Atendimento Maringá"},{"trechoorigem":null,"trechodestino":null,"dataprocessamento":null,"sobrenomepassageiro":"Teste","statusintegracao":"SUCESSO","tipoproduto":"HOTEL","datasaida":null,"dataconclusaovenda":1439450269000,"idpostoatendimento":null,"tipointegracao":"CONCLUSAO","confirmacao":null,"idintegracao":1112,"dataemissaovenda":null,"fornecedor":"470","idproduto":9467,"nomepassageiro":"Passageiro","idsolicitacao":21408,"datacriacaovenda":1439450082000,"localizador":"ADF123","datachegada":null,"localizadorgds":null,"postoatendimento":"Atendimento Maringá"},{"trechoorigem":null,"trechodestino":null,"dataprocessamento":null,"sobrenomepassageiro":null,"statusintegracao":"EM PROCESSAMENTO","tipoproduto":"AEREO","datasaida":null,"dataconclusaovenda":null,"idpostoatendimento":null,"tipointegracao":"CONCLUSAO","confirmacao":null,"idintegracao":1114,"dataemissaovenda":null,"fornecedor":null,"idproduto":20626,"nomepassageiro":null,"idsolicitacao":1,"datacriacaovenda":null,"localizador":null,"datachegada":null,"localizadorgds":null,"postoatendimento":null},{"trechoorigem":"CGH","trechodestino":"SDU","dataprocessamento":null,"sobrenomepassageiro":"TESTE","statusintegracao":"SUCESSO","tipoproduto":"AEREO","datasaida":1445519400000,"dataconclusaovenda":1445240405000,"idpostoatendimento":null,"tipointegracao":"CONCLUSAO","confirmacao":null,"idintegracao":1115,"dataemissaovenda":1445263200000,"fornecedor":"G3","idproduto":22622,"nomepassageiro":"PASSAGEIRO","idsolicitacao":22100,"datacriacaovenda":1445240352000,"localizador":"FLKH4R","datachegada":1445522880000,"localizadorgds":"false","postoatendimento":"Atendimento Maringá"},{"trechoorigem":null,"trechodestino":null,"dataprocessamento":null,"sobrenomepassageiro":null,"statusintegracao":"EM PROCESSAMENTO","tipoproduto":"HOTEL","datasaida":null,"dataconclusaovenda":null,"idpostoatendimento":null,"tipointegracao":"CONCLUSAO","confirmacao":null,"idintegracao":1116,"dataemissaovenda":null,"fornecedor":null,"idproduto":9652,"nomepassageiro":null,"idsolicitacao":21970,"datacriacaovenda":null,"localizador":null,"datachegada":null,"localizadorgds":null,"postoatendimento":null},{"trechoorigem":null,"trechodestino":null,"dataprocessamento":null,"sobrenomepassageiro":null,"statusintegracao":"EM PROCESSAMENTO","tipoproduto":"HOTEL","datasaida":null,"dataconclusaovenda":null,"idpostoatendimento":null,"tipointegracao":"CONCLUSAO","confirmacao":null,"idintegracao":1117,"dataemissaovenda":null,"fornecedor":null,"idproduto":9653,"nomepassageiro":null,"idsolicitacao":21971,"datacriacaovenda":null,"localizador":null,"datachegada":null,"localizadorgds":null,"postoatendimento":null},{"trechoorigem":null,"trechodestino":null,"dataprocessamento":null,"sobrenomepassageiro":null,"statusintegracao":"EM PROCESSAMENTO","tipoproduto":"AEREO","datasaida":null,"dataconclusaovenda":null,"idpostoatendimento":null,"tipointegracao":"CONCLUSAO","confirmacao":null,"idintegracao":1118,"dataemissaovenda":null,"fornecedor":null,"idproduto":22531,"nomepassageiro":null,"idsolicitacao":21893,"datacriacaovenda":null,"localizador":null,"datachegada":null,"localizadorgds":null,"postoatendimento":null}]';`

    var data = JSON.parse(json);
    console.log(data);

    var campos = Object.keys(data[0]);


    /* CRIAR HTML E JUNTAR O <TR> À ARRAY */
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    campos.forEach(function (titulo) {
        var th = document.createElement('th');
        th.innerHTML = titulo;
        tr.appendChild(th);
    });
    table.appendChild(tr);
    data.map(function (pessoa) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        Object.keys(pessoa).forEach(function (valor) {
            var td = document.createElement('td');
            td.innerHTML = pessoa[valor];
            tr.appendChild(td);
        });
        table.appendChild(tr);
        pessoa.DOM = tr;
        return pessoa;
    });
    document.body.appendChild(table);

    /* PARTE DE FILTRAGENS */
    var select = document.querySelector('select');
    var input = document.querySelector('input');
    var button = document.querySelector('button');
    button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        var prop = select.value;
        var val = input.value;
        data.forEach(function (linha) {
            var valor = linha[prop];
            if (valor && linha[prop].indexOf(val) < 0) linha.DOM.classList.add('esconder');
            else linha.DOM.classList.remove('esconder');
        });
    });

}
</script>

<body>
    <form action="testeste.html" method="post">
        <select>
            <option value="trechoorigem">Trecho Origem</option>
            <option value="trechodestino">Trecho Destino</option>
            <option value="dataprocessamento">Data Processamento</option>
            <option value="statusintegracao">Status Integração</option>
            <option value="tipoproduto">Tipo Produto</option>
            <option value="datasaida">Data Saida</option>
            <option value="dataconclusaovenda">Conclusão Venda</option>
            <option value="idpostoatendimento">ID P.Atendimento</option>
            <option value="tipointegracao">Tipo Integração</option>
            <option value="confirmacao">Confirmação</option>
            <option value="idintegracao">ID Integração</option>
            <option value="dataemissaovenda">Data Emissao Venda</option>
            <option value="fornecedor">Fornecedor</option>
            <option value="idproduto">ID Produto</option>
            <option value="nomepassageiro">Nome Passageiro</option>
            <option value="idsolicitacao">ID Solicitação</option>
            <option value="datacriacaovenda">Data Criação Venda</option>
            <option value="datachegada">Data Chegada</option>
            <option value="localizadorgds">Localizador GDS</option>
            <option value="postoatendimento">Posto de Atendimento</option>

        </select>
        <input type="text" />
        <button onclick="executa()">Pesquisar</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Alguma dica?

Comment: Coloca o teu script no final da página. Do jeito que está o browser vai rodar o script antes de renderizar os elementos...

Comment: o jsfiddle contém autoload no corpo, então acredito que seja só fazer isso:  `$(function(){ //aqui seu codigo... });`

Comment: E no caso do jsfiddle que vc colocou: precisa de `ondomreadOnly`

Comment: @IvanFerrer não entendi o que você propôs, com o `ondomreadOnly`. Mas funcionou colocando o script no fim do `HTML`.

Comment: Não propus nada, só comentei que no jsfiddle que você publicou a opção "ondomreadOnly" está habilitada. O script não funcionará enquanto o seu body não estiver carregado. Por isso não funciona no começo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coloca o teu script no final da página. Do jeito que está o browser vai rodar o script antes de renderizar os elementos. Veja:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt-BR">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <style>
        th, td {
            padding: 5px;
            border:1px solid black;
        }
        .esconder {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    
    <form action="testeste.html" method="post">
        <select>
            <option value="trechoorigem">Trecho Origem</option>
            <option value="trechodestino">Trecho Destino</option>
            <option value="dataprocessamento">Data Processamento</option>
            <option value="statusintegracao">Status Integração</option>
            <option value="tipoproduto">Tipo Produto</option>
            <option value="datasaida">Data Saida</option>
            <option value="dataconclusaovenda">Conclusão Venda</option>
            <option value="idpostoatendimento">ID P.Atendimento</option>
            <option value="tipointegracao">Tipo Integração</option>
            <option value="confirmacao">Confirmação</option>
            <option value="idintegracao">ID Integração</option>
            <option value="dataemissaovenda">Data Emissao Venda</option>
            <option value="fornecedor">Fornecedor</option>
            <option value="idproduto">ID Produto</option>
            <option value="nomepassageiro">Nome Passageiro</option>
            <option value="idsolicitacao">ID Solicitação</option>
            <option value="datacriacaovenda">Data Criação Venda</option>
            <option value="datachegada">Data Chegada</option>
            <option value="localizadorgds">Localizador GDS</option>
            <option value="postoatendimento">Posto de Atendimento</option>

        </select>
        <input type="text" type="button"/>
        <button onclick="executa()">Pesquisar</button>
        </form>
  </body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var json = '[{"trechoorigem":"CGH","trechodestino":"CWB","dataprocessamento":null,"sobrenomepassageiro":"TESTE","statusintegracao":"PENDENTE","tipoproduto":"AEREO","datasaida":1440069600000,"dataconclusaovenda":1438345534000,"idpostoatendimento":null,"tipointegracao":"CONCLUSAO","confirmacao":null,"idintegracao":1113,"dataemissaovenda":1438354800000,"fornecedor":"JJ","idproduto":22078,"nomepassageiro":"PASSAGEIRO","idsolicitacao":21192,"datacriacaovenda":1438345245000,"localizador":"5RAHNZ","datachegada":1440073380000,"localizadorgds":"false","postoatendimento":"Atendimento Maringá"},{"trechoorigem":null,"trechodestino":null,"dataprocessamento":null,"sobrenomepassageiro":"Teste","statusintegracao":"SUCESSO","tipoproduto":"HOTEL","datasaida":null,"dataconclusaovenda":1439450269000,"idpostoatendimento":null,"tipointegracao":"CONCLUSAO","confirmacao":null,"idintegracao":1112,"dataemissaovenda":null,"fornecedor":"470","idproduto":9467,"nomepassageiro":"Passageiro","idsolicitacao":21408,"datacriacaovenda":1439450082000,"localizador":"ADF123","datachegada":null,"localizadorgds":null,"postoatendimento":"Atendimento Maringá"},{"trechoorigem":null,"trechodestino":null,"dataprocessamento":null,"sobrenomepassageiro":null,"statusintegracao":"EM PROCESSAMENTO","tipoproduto":"AEREO","datasaida":null,"dataconclusaovenda":null,"idpostoatendimento":null,"tipointegracao":"CONCLUSAO","confirmacao":null,"idintegracao":1114,"dataemissaovenda":null,"fornecedor":null,"idproduto":20626,"nomepassageiro":null,"idsolicitacao":1,"datacriacaovenda":null,"localizador":null,"datachegada":null,"localizadorgds":null,"postoatendimento":null},{"trechoorigem":"CGH","trechodestino":"SDU","dataprocessamento":null,"sobrenomepassageiro":"TESTE","statusintegracao":"SUCESSO","tipoproduto":"AEREO","datasaida":1445519400000,"dataconclusaovenda":1445240405000,"idpostoatendimento":null,"tipointegracao":"CONCLUSAO","confirmacao":null,"idintegracao":1115,"dataemissaovenda":1445263200000,"fornecedor":"G3","idproduto":22622,"nomepassageiro":"PASSAGEIRO","idsolicitacao":22100,"datacriacaovenda":1445240352000,"localizador":"FLKH4R","datachegada":1445522880000,"localizadorgds":"false","postoatendimento":"Atendimento Maringá"},{"trechoorigem":null,"trechodestino":null,"dataprocessamento":null,"sobrenomepassageiro":null,"statusintegracao":"EM PROCESSAMENTO","tipoproduto":"HOTEL","datasaida":null,"dataconclusaovenda":null,"idpostoatendimento":null,"tipointegracao":"CONCLUSAO","confirmacao":null,"idintegracao":1116,"dataemissaovenda":null,"fornecedor":null,"idproduto":9652,"nomepassageiro":null,"idsolicitacao":21970,"datacriacaovenda":null,"localizador":null,"datachegada":null,"localizadorgds":null,"postoatendimento":null},{"trechoorigem":null,"trechodestino":null,"dataprocessamento":null,"sobrenomepassageiro":null,"statusintegracao":"EM PROCESSAMENTO","tipoproduto":"HOTEL","datasaida":null,"dataconclusaovenda":null,"idpostoatendimento":null,"tipointegracao":"CONCLUSAO","confirmacao":null,"idintegracao":1117,"dataemissaovenda":null,"fornecedor":null,"idproduto":9653,"nomepassageiro":null,"idsolicitacao":21971,"datacriacaovenda":null,"localizador":null,"datachegada":null,"localizadorgds":null,"postoatendimento":null},{"trechoorigem":null,"trechodestino":null,"dataprocessamento":null,"sobrenomepassageiro":null,"statusintegracao":"EM PROCESSAMENTO","tipoproduto":"AEREO","datasaida":null,"dataconclusaovenda":null,"idpostoatendimento":null,"tipointegracao":"CONCLUSAO","confirmacao":null,"idintegracao":1118,"dataemissaovenda":null,"fornecedor":null,"idproduto":22531,"nomepassageiro":null,"idsolicitacao":21893,"datacriacaovenda":null,"localizador":null,"datachegada":null,"localizadorgds":null,"postoatendimento":null}]';

var data = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(data);

var campos = Object.keys(data[0]);


/* CRIAR HTML E JUNTAR O <TR> À ARRAY */
var table = document.createElement('table');
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
campos.forEach(function (titulo) {
    var th = document.createElement('th');
    th.innerHTML = titulo;
    tr.appendChild(th);
});
table.appendChild(tr);
data.map(function (pessoa) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    Object.keys(pessoa).forEach(function (valor) {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        td.innerHTML = pessoa[valor];
        tr.appendChild(td);
    });
    table.appendChild(tr);
    pessoa.DOM = tr;
    return pessoa;
});
document.body.appendChild(table);

/* PARTE DE FILTRAGENS */
var select = document.querySelector('select');
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var prop = select.value;
    var val = input.value;
    data.forEach(function (linha) {
        var valor = linha[prop];
        if (valor && linha[prop].indexOf(val) < 0) linha.DOM.classList.add('esconder');
        else linha.DOM.classList.remove('esconder');
    });
});

        
    </script>


        </html>
```

Comment: É apenas parte do problema. De considerar também as alterações que ele fez no script original ao copiá-lo para o arquivo html.
Outro ponto é que ao se colocar um <button> sem um [type] definido dentro de um <form>, o browser o trata como [type=submit], fazendo  postback toda vez que o botão for clicado.
Logo o button deve ter seu tipo especificado  <button type="button">

Comment: @Moykn Deu certinho, valeu!!

Valeu ai também ai Emir!

Comment: Eu percebi que quando clico no botão ele executa normalmente o filtro, mas quando pressiono enter ele recarrega a página, sabe o motivo disso?

Comment: tem que ver em qual elemento o foco está posicionado